# Entity Frame - Record Last Access Date

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have figured out how to store CreatedAt and LastModifiedAt, but I also want to record LastAccessedAt.

This would record the last time a call to `/api/thing/1` was made. It currently looks like this:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Thing))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetThing(int id)
    {
        var patient = new ThingDetailDTO(
            db.Things.First(t => t.Id == id)
        );

        if (thing== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(thing);
    }
```

I was thinking of overloading the .First() call.

I would want the solution to be generic enough so that I can abstract it away, instead of having to copy-paste it onto every similar method I have.

Comment: Search for the Generic Repository Pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use action filter attribute where you can override the onactionexecuted method and access the response object and log or update the database by the accessed at date time.  See this link which has some good examples that may give a starting point. http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/

Hope that helps.